# $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {n^2} =\frac {\pi ^2}{6}$ and $ S_i =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{i} {(36n^2-1)^i}$ . Find $S_1 + S_2 $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I know to find sum of series using method of difference. I tried sum of write the term as (6n-1)(6n+1). i don't know how to proceed further.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
S_1+S_2&=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{36n^2-1}+\frac{2}{(36n^2-1)^2}\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(6n-1)^2}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{(6n+1)^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\substack{n\geq 5\\n\equiv \pm1\,\!\!\!\mod 6}}\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\equiv 0\!\!\!\mod 2}}\frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\equiv 0\!\!\!\mod 3}}\frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\n\equiv 0\!\!\!\mod 6}}\frac{1}{n^2}-1\right]\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{4}\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{1}{9}\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1\right]\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{18}-\frac{1}{2}.
\end{align*}

Comment: how can i explain 4th step, if one does not know modulo math.can it be explained in easier way

Comment: @raj, then why did you accept his answer? Because it doesn't really answers your question. Even though he gave the answer but it contains modulo which you said that you don't want. I think you should accept Hazem Orabi's answer because didn't used modulo.

Comment: @RanjitKumarSarkar, raj didn't say he didn't want modulo. I said that.

Comment: @aarbee. 

Answer (score 8):

Expand and split
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}&=\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{1^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{2^2}}\right)+\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{3^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{4^2}}\right)+\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{5^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{6^2}}\right)+\cdots \\[2mm] 
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}}+\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n\right)^2}} \\[2mm] 
&=\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}} 
\end{align} \\ 
\space\Rightarrow\space \boxed{\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}}=\frac{3}{4}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{8}} 
$$

Expand again
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}&=1+\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{{3}^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{{5}^2}}+\color{magenta}{\frac{1}{{7}^2}}\right)+\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{{9}^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{{11}^2}}+\color{magenta}{\frac{1}{{13}^2}}\right)+\left(\color{blue}{\frac{1}{{15}^2}}+\color{red}{\frac{1}{{17}^2}}+\color{magenta}{\frac{1}{{19}^2}}\right)+\cdots \\[2mm] 
&=1+\color{blue}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n-3\right)^2}}+\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n-1\right)^2}}+\color{magenta}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n+1\right)^2}} \\[2mm] 
&=1+\color{blue}{\frac{1}{9}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}}+\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n-1\right)^2}}+\color{magenta}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n+1\right)^2}} 
\end{align} \\ 
\space\Rightarrow\space \boxed{\color{red}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n-1\right)^2}}+\color{magenta}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(6n+1\right)^2}}=\frac{8}{9}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(2n-1\right)^2}-1=\frac{\pi^2}{9}-1} 
$$

Simplify
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\frac{2}{\left(36n^2-1\right)^2}&=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{2}{(6n-1)(6n+1)}\right]^2=\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{6n-1}-\frac{1}{6n+1}\right]^2 \\[2mm] 
&=\frac{1/2}{\left(6n-1\right)^2}+\frac{1/2}{\left(6n+1\right)^2}-\frac{1}{36n^2-1} 
\end{align} 
$$
Claculate
$$ 
\begin{align} 
\color{red}{S_1+S_2}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{36n^2-1}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\left(36n^2-1\right)^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1/2}{\left(6n-1\right)^2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1/2}{\left(6n+1\right)^2} \\[2mm] 
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{\left(6n-1\right)^2}+\frac{1}{\left(6n+1\right)^2}\right]=\color{red}{\frac{\pi^2}{18}-\frac{1}{2}} 
\end{align} 
$$

Comment: that's beautiful, thanks.

Comment: @aarbee : Thanks for the words & the rewards.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know about the polygamma functions, first write
$$(36n^2-1)^2=(6n+1)^2(6n-1)^2$$ and perform a first partial fraction decomposition
$$\frac 2{(36n^2-1)^2}=\frac{1}{2 (6 n+1)}-\frac{1}{2 (6 n-1)}+\frac{1}{2 (6 n+1)^2}+\frac{1}{2 (6 n-1)^2}$$
Computing the partial sum
$$\Sigma_p=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac 2{(36n^2-1)^2}=$$ $$\Bigg[\frac{1}{12} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(p+\frac{7}{6}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)\right) \Bigg]-\Bigg[\frac{1}{12} \left(\psi ^{(0)}\left(p+\frac{5}{6}\right)-\psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)\right) \Bigg]+\Bigg[\frac{1}{72} \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(p+\frac{7}{6}\right)\right) \Bigg]+\Bigg[\frac{1}{72} \left(\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)-\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(p+\frac{5}{6}\right)\right) \Bigg]$$

Now, using the asymptotics
$$\Sigma_p=\frac{1}{72} \left(6 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)-6 \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{1944 p^3}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^4}\right)$$ Thus
$$S_2=\frac{1}{72} \left(6 \psi ^{(0)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)-6 \psi
   ^{(0)}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)+\psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)+\psi
   ^{(1)}\left(\frac{7}{6}\right)\right)=-1+\frac{\pi }{4 \sqrt{3}}+\frac{\pi ^2}{18}$$

$$S_1+S_2=\frac{2 \pi ^2}{9}+\frac{\pi }{4 \sqrt{3}}-1\sim 1.64670 $$

Obviously, this is not the same result as in other answers.

I must say that I do not understand how, adding positive terms to $S_1$, we could have a vlaue smaller then $\frac{ \pi ^2}{6} \sim 1.64493$.